# Force child classes to override a particular function in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am creating a reporting library in PHP and developed an abstract class named **ReportView**. This will provide the basic functionality of a report like Generating header and footer, create parameter form.

There will be another function named **generate_report** in this class. Currently it is empty in abstract class as at this level we do not know the contents of report. Further it includes a **render** function which calls this generate_report function and sends output to browser.

> So I need whenever a child class inherits from ReportView it must implement
>   the generate_report method otherwise PHP must give error. Is there any keyword or method through which we can enforce implemetation of a specific function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do the following:

```
abstract class ReportView {
  abstract protected function generate_report();

  // snip ...

}

class Report extends ReportView {
  protected function generate_report() { /* snip */ }
}
```

Any class that extends `ReportView` and is not abstract *must* implement `generate_report` (and any other abstract function in its super classes for that matter).

Comment: is this possible for static methods?

Comment: Nope. If you need this for static methods, it is a strong sign that your code is "too static". You might need to move some of the static methods to their own class (a factory is a typical example of this).

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you’d be better off creating an interface, which would enforce you to define those methods in classes that then implement this interface.

```
<?php
interface ReportInterface {
    public function generate();
}

class MyReportClass implements ReportInterface {
}
```

Instantiating `MyReportClass` here will throw a fatal error, telling you `generate()` has not been implemented.

**Edit:** You can also create abstract classes that implement this interface. You can have your abstract class contain any methods all extending classes need, and have your interface define any methods you need to be defined by extending classes.

Comment: Not necessarily. He may have some implemented methods in the base class.

Comment: can it be like: class MyReport extends ReportView Implements ReportInterface { }

Comment: @Mark In which case the OP can create an abstract class that implements `ReportInterface`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Interface can be used but I think the report view class has to be defined only once so Making the generate_method abstract will be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the method as `abstract` as well (and don't give it a method body), otherwise the derived classes will not be forced to implement it.

Alternatively, you could implement the method but have it just throw an Exception (not sure why you would want to do this).

Lastly, if *all* the methods in your base class are "abstract" (do not have bodies) then you can make the class into an Interface instead.

Comment: The base class ReportView has to be defined only once, so why would I need an interface?

Comment: What do you mean "only has to be defined once"? If all the methods in `ReportView` are abstract then there's really not much difference between your "pure" abstract class and an Interface, except that you're allowed to inherit multiple interfaces.